# knowing if an event ocurred (when running gtk_dialog_run() )

Tags: linux, gcc, event-handling, gtk

How do You determine what control/widget was clicked inside a dialog box by checking the return value of `gtk_dialog_run()`

This is what I have

```
/*toolbar test thingy*/
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#define MESSAGE_OK 1001

void mymessage (void){
    GtkWidget *message = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons("My dialog",
        NULL,
        GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,GTK_STOCK_OK,1001,NULL);

    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(message),200,200);

    gint result = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(message));
    switch(result){
        case MESSAGE_OK:
            gtk_widget_destroy(message);
            printf("you clicked message_ok");
        break;


    }
    gtk_widget_destroy(message);
}


int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vertical_box;
    GtkWidget *toolbar;
    //GtkWidget *message;

    GtkToolItem *tool_new;


    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

    //setting up the main window.
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"rs-toolbar test");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),300,350);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);

    //setting up the layout using vbox.
    vertical_box = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,0);
    //adding the vbox layout to the Container window, window
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),vertical_box);

    toolbar = gtk_toolbar_new();
    gtk_toolbar_set_style(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar),GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(toolbar),2);

    tool_new = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_NEW);
    gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar),tool_new,-1);
    //************************************************************************





    //************************************************************************
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vertical_box),toolbar,FALSE,FALSE,0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    g_signal_connect(window,"destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
    g_signal_connect(tool_new,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(mymessage),NULL);

    gtk_main();



    return 0;

}
```

Is the use of the `gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons()` function correct?. I'm not entirely sure how to give a specific ID to a control. What I've tried to do there is make 1001 the ID of `GTK_STOCK_OK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing the response to the wrong thing.  `gtk_dialog_run` returns one of the [GTK_RESPONSE](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/2.21/GtkDialog.html#GTK-RESPONSE-NONE%3aCAPS) constants; try comparing against those in your switch to see which button was pressed.

Comment: What happened?  *It didn't work* isn't really enough detail to work from :)